# JQuery Animation Complete Function: How to recover my "old this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm getting started with jQuery and I have the following problem:

```
function AClass(){
    this.attribute = /*something*/
}

AClass.prototype.COMPLETE= function() {
    /*FROM HERE I WANT TO ACCESS TO THE ABOVE "this.attribute"!!*/
}

AClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    $("something").animate(..,..,.., this.COMPLETE);
}
```

So, that's the problem I'm facing. From that Complete animation function I want to access the value of the attribute of the AClass. The thing is that in that context `this` is pointing to the DOM element being animated and no longer pointing to the caller object.

Comment: Not directly related to what you're asking, but why are you setting properties on the prototype from _inside_ the constructor function? These properties will then be overwritten every time you create a new `AClass` object.

Comment: I'm getting started with javascript, and as far as a know, doing that every instance share the same piece of code, otherwhise evey instance of the Class is going to have a copy of the same code which isn't optimal (in short, every instance inherit the methods from the class prototype property, and as a result they all point to the same code)

Comment: That's the idea, but normally you'd assign the prototype methods and properties _outside_ the constructor function (usually immediately afterwards).

Comment: yup ... although I think it's kind of messy I'm going to take you advice since I realized that, even though the result is the same, I'm creating a bit of overhead every time a instanciate the class I re-assign the methods, am I wrong?

Comment: now I am where I started... since the method AClass.prototype.COMPLETE is out of the AClass function definition, the variable "self" (see the answer) is not longer reachable from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$.proxy()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to bind a particular context to your callback. Or if you're not concerned about old browsers (i.e., IE < 9) you can use the (JS 1.8.5) [`.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). Basically where you need to supply `yourFunction` as a callback put:

```
$.proxy(yourFunction, theRequiredContext)
// or
yourFunction.bind(theRequiredContext)
```

In the context of your example code:

```
function AClass(){
    this.attribute = /*something*/
}

AClass.prototype.COMPLETE= function() {
    /*FROM HERE I WANT TO ACCESS TO THE ABOVE "this.attribute"!!*/
}

AClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    $("something").animate(..,..,..,$.proxy(this.COMPLETE, this));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P9mbG/

Comment: awesome! you're great! so I let the proxy function execute the COMPLETE function code for me in the context given as its second input argument (in this case 'this'), thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Save a reference to the orginal this in a variable:

```
function AClass(){
    this.attribute = /*something*/
    var self = this;

    AClass.prototype.COMPLETE= function() {
        /* Use: self.attributes */
    }

    AClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        $("something").animate(..,..,..,COMPLETE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! it worked! at least so far xD thanks for helping me! I appreciate it

Comment: Have you tested this with more than one instance of `AClass`? Because with `COMPLETE` being a method of the prototype all instances will reference the same `COMPLETE` so all will reference the `self` variable of the last instance. (Or, if the the prototype methods were declared after the constructor function, as is more usual, this closure mechanism wouldn't work at all.)